# Volatile and compiler optimization

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, volatile

Is it OK to say that 'volatile' keyword makes no difference if the compiler optimization is turned off i.e (gcc -o0 ....)?

I had made some sample 'C' program and seeing the difference between volatile and non-volatile in the generated assembly code  only when the compiler optimization is turned on i.e ((gcc -o1 ....).

Comment: I suspect it would depend on whether the variable in question can be handled with an atomic operation on the target, so there is no chance of an interrupt leaving it in an inconsitent state.

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no basis for making such a statement.

`volatile` has specific semantics that are spelled out in the standard. You are asserting that `gcc -O0` always generates code such that every variable -- `volatile` or not -- conforms to those semantics. This is not guaranteed; even if it happens to be the case for a particular program and a particular version of `gcc`, it could well change when, for example, you upgrade your compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Probably `volatile` does not make much difference with `gcc -O0` -for GCC 4.7 or earlier. However, this is probably changing in the next version of GCC (i.e. future 4.8, that is current trunk). And the next version will also provide `-Og` to get debug-friendly optimization.

In GCC 4.7 and earlier no optimizations mean that values are not always kept in registers from one C (or even Gimple, that is the internal representation inside GCC) instruction to the next.

Also, `volatile` has a specific meaning, both for standard conforming compilers and for human. For instance, I would be upset if reading some code with a `sig_atomic_t` variable which is *not* `volatile`!

BTW, you could use the `-fdump-tree-all` option to GCC to get a lot of dump files, or use the [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) domain specific language and plugin, notably its [probe](http://gcc-melt.org/#probe_id) to query the GCC internal representations thru a graphical interface.